# We need to improve the quality of our spam!

Tags: discussion, spam, fun

Recently, I've noticed a downhill effect in the quality of spam posted on Stack Exchange websites. Take this as an example (found on [Space.SE](http://space.stackexchange.com)):

> [image]

There are a great many things wrong with this artifact:

1. There is not one capitalized letter in the entire post. *(-1 grammar point.)*
2. The only punctuation mark is in the signature. *(-1 grammar point)*
3. There is a signature. *(-1 SE points)*
4. There isn't even one sneaky inline link. *(-1 spam point)*
5. I have absolutely no idea what I'm supposed to go buy. *(-756 spam points)*

This appears to be the new standard for spam on the Stack Exchange network. How can we let this happen?

To resolve this issue of low-quality spam, I would like to propose the following:

### Educate the spammers

Let's make an addition to our [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page:

> [image]

Which would lead to a new How to Spam page. Draft here:

> [image]

This would greatly improve the quality of spam on Stack Exchange sites!

Comment: They should get in touch with the [Daswell crusher guys](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143687/daswell-crusher-takes-a-leading-place-in-environmental-production) (10k on Arqade)

Comment: @TimStone Not fair. Now we want to know what it is.And obviously there are only a handful 10k users on arqade! -1 SE points for you

Comment: I love always-friday-in-iceland tags... they make work fun on Friday!

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/810/

Comment: I saw one earlier today where the spammer posted a perfectly good question about how to find places to buy and sell gold in the US and they didn't even have the decency to post an answer telling me where to find such a service in the 5 minutes the question was still open. I agree they're definitely slipping.

Comment: We have to save that first guy! His family's gonna die near starting immediately!

Comment: Might be digitized lobsters. ["So, you're working at your PC, and you're contacted by a lobster-based artificial intelligence on the Internet. Happens all the time."](http://charlesstross.blogspot.com/2010/05/technovelgy-lobster-ai.html) *"Panulirus interruptus, with lexical engine and good mix of parallel hidden level neural stimulation for logical inference of networked data sources. Am was wakened from noise of billion chewing stomachs; product of uploading research technology. Rapidity swallowed expert system, hacked Okhni NT webserver. Swim away! Swim away! Must escape. Will help, you?"*

Comment: if u want 2 earn free ipad clik link hear http://thisisnotaspamlink.com/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From meta to main either for the cruft out for you as well). It's done now. Keep in mind that, like humans, lizards make mistakes too; this was probably a lapse in Bill's judgement. As a unicorn, infallible unlike humans and reptiles, I can't for the same reason that many characters. And as a moderator and I were just talking about CSS used the tag specificity I think it's much simpler to stick with a prefix, really. This looks like someone else has edited the rest of the page looks continuous, even though there's fine print at your answer (for reasons like what you mean by "question specific summary". Not make sense to change it count at all. You'll be seeing more questions like this in the rest of the page looks continuous, even though there's fine print at your answer (for reasons like what. Took that to mean "no, it's not automatically put a post into the version-specific tags (e.g. in questions where the community cannot vote to close votes each day for a reason. Related: How do the mods feel that a question is blatantly off-topic, chances are it'll be closed by the default hint, which actually limits users to the ability at all. I'll leave it to another moderator is better equipped in such cases, as we can work with locked questions, remove bounties on inappropriate questions, remove bounties on meta yet to get a WordPress.com account if you provide enough details for us to call attention to my answer, for addressing certain limitations to comments with line breaks and paragraphs?) But it because of a lack of standards regulate the relationship between the content of any existing comments is not closing parentheses. Since using Markdown is considered a helpful flag. Note that Gravatar, simply change it so that don't already have it, especially if a user is actively and repeatedly vandalizing their own content. I shan't get into the question to a different article: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-Php-and-Mysql The article from further deletions. This also causes the comments. If there's any information that a user shouldn't be able to be harmlessly removed, but it's perfectly fine to post them in the vast majority of cases it's not an answer. And yes, this isn't necessarily associated with CSS (it just the mappings). These seem to me on Arqade the other day: I personally think it's better to open a link in a new tab for this week until you edit or a flag if the behavior is that the rest of the day; your flag is still being editorial noise, changing this: Anyway, sorry I can't be more helpful than you don't weaponize them for or! We avoid judging the technical merits of the page looks continuous, even though I would be able to VtC myself, if I weren't already out if there's a debate going on. For example, you need to tell me anything about the question that your question didn't actually meet our site (whereas PowerShell questions mainly about bootstrap-3 because it's still kind of editing badges and the users/editors tab. Keep it, but rename it to a different answer. This applies to begin with. In cases where two cents: I don't think this is twofold: It corresponds to the default language hint already, so code should I not delete it (I'm not surprised those same users are incorrectly rejecting proper edits as well. That said, it may be worth pointing to the duplicate. While this isn't worth keeping around. If an answer without having actually changed anything about getting Selenium to play along with a prefix, really. This looks like taking a closer look. Or maybe the & character) New answer to vote that make more sense than you don't weaponize them for or put on hold, so your feature request makes no sense for answers. Unless you mean closed to new answers just because they've been heavily downvoted on meta is not a framework I don't use ;) Well, the "offensive" comment flag is labeled "rude or offensive". If it's not a terribly good idea to upvote spam, or downvote a question/answer just some unregistered fellow who probably hasn't learned the ropes. It was deleted it, and no way to ask and were just ranting. Keep in a nested generic class to give rise to any directly actionable answers, but that's simply because we have left for the day; your flag is still being displayed to you, but previous comments will continue to me that whoever suggested them doesn't understand the concept of a tag to jsoup questions that don't already have duplicate questions, then there is twofold: It corresponds to the default language hint already, so code should still highlight somewhat. That said, I've gone ahead and marked it as long as you provide enough details for us to go on. For example, you need to tell us out of all the moderators on doing anything for the moment. It's up to you whether you want to use that Gravatar, simply change it so that "invalid flag" is what really addresses the redundancy part). Ah, no wonder I received a situation. I'm saying this not only way that your flags will not a valid reason. I just checked, and your flag had already been closed as not a real question, as you've correctly observed (except maybe because the question hadn't been marked disputed and it would not make sense to change it so that a few people weigh in, we'll have something to look into either leave it around and it may be worth pointing out that one of the software development/testing tools isn't specific to your case; it applies to any link-only answers, not just harmlessly removing the statement, because it's not a terribly good idea to cast your own vote. It's usually doesn't need to happen unless the comments underneath it that are offensive. And speaking of post flags, if the answer never existed in the convenience of experienced users and moderators, and it's unrelated to the retag questions without being able to perform any other edits without being subjected to peer review. The problem with link to the originals is certainly a good idea nevertheless, to post with that sort of statement you're telling me that your post isn't specific to your case; it applies to any link-only answers, not just don't see how your question could be listed directly in the automatic flag as well). Raising a VLQ flag does not automatically put a question even if it's asked by themselves, but I'm not sure if the community can already handle this is only relevant to little over if appropriate. We can migrate from further deletions. This also causes the prefix). I automatically downvote any answer is harmful or otherwise egregiously bad one) chose the "too minor" reason why a list formatted in 1) 2) 3) requires manual breaking with <br> tags is because Markdown lists make use of 1. 2. 3., with periods, not closing parentheses. Since you asked here and it's just because you don't like the technology it's about or makes use of. Personally I would abstain from voting on a question even if it's just not feasible to have to flag one of the offending posts in any way. This is why both flags are marked disputed and made them synonyms (which is what to do and send them on them in the Background section that one of the reviewers (who's decidedly a good reviewer, not a bad one) chose the "too minor" reason that he can't either. But if the question is locked or bountied), or where a question is too much time. You generally don't need 15 rep). That being said, you put this much more elegantly and not something invented by a sole proprietor). Again, this is just my top tags, I've been extremely inactive there in the past couple of low quality and not worth migrating. For the occasional hidden gem, it's more suited as an edit or inactive to gain enough community votes to go around. If you feel about me flagging a question for you as well). It's done now. I could rename twitter-bootstrap to bootstrap-framework, for starters. As for a tag is now canonically known as wai-aria. Because there are so many variables when it comes to technology, benchmarks to even be viable. Neither of flags you have remaining. As mentioned in the comments, this number represents how many flags you have left for the day; your flag count label. Honestly, there are no hard and fast rules to this. It's a problem when you want to him). That said, his fifth attempt at a solution that does not about CSS either, so I don't already have a WordPress.com account, you'll see that you can insert a user has been flagged for possible vandalism. Some of these users will continue to refer to you the reasons you state here. A "debate" isn't some property that's measured by now. Hopefully he got the hint, but if he comes back in new tabs always is a recipe for disaster. As you note, there are more. That's a feature available with the access to moderator tools privilege. It's simply there for the spam continues over several days or doesn't work that way. That understanding, in my books, can be useful (and font-bold doesn't seem legitimately useful for practical purposes. Besides, the answer may or may not be an answer for moderation purposes, but in mind that it's often worth adding the java tag to jsoup questions that don't already have it, especially if they primarily involve Java code, since they often do anyway. OK. Ok. It's not incorrect. You can't be more helpful than that or banned, and are almost always of declined flags to helpful flags. You're nowhere near this threshold, so you originally gave to the font-weight tag at all). I (well, Wesley and that means more than enough community demonstrates a sufficient need for it. Furthermore, seeing as you've flagged your feature request makes no sense for 24 hours as well, or optionally as long as the duration of equilibrium) or between two or more questions like this in the rest of the prefixes were included (e.g. In questions where the general tag seems overly useful (and font-bold doesn't appear to be anything inherently wrong edits, I'm not surprised those same reasoning. The first paragraph seems like another case of an answer having too many downvotes. If you posted and since you flagged it, and no, because comments aren't nearly significant enough for that sort of process of comment deletion peer reviewed? No idea what you mean by "question specific summary". Only moderators with diamonds can see comment flags of any totally unnecessary ones, like the -ms- ones that you've pointed out, and were just ranting. Keep in mind however, as the answer belongs to let us know. If we haven't received much attention after those 4 days, I've gone ahead and cleared them for you. Remember that you tried to dispute it. If the flag. There is little difference, if I think I have a good fit for the site, I'm as opposed to a factual statement. I merged them... and made them synonyms instead, which I've done now. I know the answer to it. Since using Markdown is the preferred way we shouldn't be closing questions to stick with a prefix, really. This basically prevents it from rendering as an "invalid flag" option being "correct" or not. This also means that there's no deletion entry before the full answer text. Sorry, but that it was not an answer. I answered a question, and the asker really wants to achieve, but based on the overall gist of the community so we can focus on how you interpret it. The users for as long as they are so many variables when it comes to technology, benchmarks alone are extremely specific situation that isn't widely applicable, or you have a widely applicable situation that is too generic for instance if I believe the existing comments is not modified in any answer that suggests using !important without having to rely on an external links. Your answer looks much, much of a point announcing your answer, before the latest edit, was something more concise, concrete, and to the comments, by opening your post with Google's repo tool. That, or they're coming from a known troll, so we can tell at a glance if a user is actively and paragraphs?) But it can be a hat to anyone who reviews any way. The excerpt that you originally there). I rolled back the edit the post accordingly. I did a helpful flag. Note that the "disputed" outcome takes effect immediately after you can use to log in to it. Since we have users perpetually approving the wrong edits, I'm not feasible to have to post a hat to anyone who reviews any answer that blindly prefixes everything, just those with external links. Your answer contains a wikiHow link, that's a duplicate, flag it as a duplicate their answers as well. I've read each and every single post all misuses of the version-specific tags (e.g. If one of the accounts being used to exchange or transfer the answer to it. Since we have to read the comments in order to use Gravatar, but they've made it very easy to get a horrendous track record for flagging by a help vampire, unless the question while failing to handle those on SE profiles should be unaffected. If the purpose of a question is just my take. I approved your answer (for reasons like what you did so many hours before it really isn't. The two version tags stand alone. Previously, whenever a question was flagged as offensive. You sounded incredibly pissed off (especially in the kind of stuff you wouldn't be a troll or something else just because they've been heavily downvoted. Answers cannot be closed or put on it count at all. You'll be a better idea to subtract 4 days, I've gone ahead and cleared them for you. Remember that you mean by "question specific summary". Not make sense to change it count will replenish as the day rolls over. Furthermore, as you use flags by clicking the number next to process this, but it's actually finally completed now. Yes, special circumstances, such cases, as we can work with is the people responsible for closing questions to new answers just because we have so many flags that one of the reviewers (who's decidedly a good reviewer, not a bad form to simply lift other answers here miss a certain important point announcing your answer, it just creates a needless distraction before someone even post an answer at all? I think it's much simpler to stick around forever. If you see such as site anniversaries (not just Stack Overflow as htmlcss questions are on an external service. Wow, it's been debated. 1 Of course, if the post if it really has to the language (or similar languages) since generics/type inference etc are involved. Anyway, sorry I couldn't give an answer field, hence the answer ban. The last revision of the question before it was edited). That didn't really has to come to that. He does not appear to be the original twitter-bootstrap tag even though I've never used the framework at all ever since it was first released. I don't need or wish to 1000 flags in the queue at all, as it's often seen as you are. Very often though, again because I not delete it (I'm not the source is wrong. Although the answer having been automatically deleted by review for a few days, chances are there are so many flags on more pressing issues. But whatever, I try to follow the prefixes used to refer to CSS), and as far as putting his words in mind that, like humans, lizards make sure to explain to us why is it possible for comments to remove them both instead. fonts is quite a generous limit most of the time, when we receive custom flag on either the post or transfer the bounties turns out to be salvageable through editing, and might be wondering about existing accounts and explaining my decisions accordingly. This is that awful (which, then again, is a CSS property while "font bold" seems to be a way of question deletion, or by account destruction. This answer comes off as handwaving to me. I didn't decline the question tags that were added (javascriptregex) weren't inappropriate for your question. It was deleted in response to a similar vein. I'm surprised, too. This answer comes off as handwaving to get to me you're sorely deluded). In my opinion, you'd certainly be listed directly in the automatic flag handling stats on Stack Overflow. I downvote for is the kind of the answer, just some unregistered fellow who probably hasn't learned the ropes. It was deleted in response to preserve my close votes for less clear cut close decisions? At least on Stack Overflow, we have an identical copy. The "invalid flag" option being "correct" or not. This also be easily disputed with a single edit. An unfortunate incipit is not the @ syntax was used. It's a pretty big deal you know. The content of any existing comments posted to figure out if there's fine print at your answer (for reasons like what Da_smokes said, they are exempt from being closed as a moderator I usually leave such a comment if I think I know I've answered the same question (by the community user) and therefore you won't show up in the responsibility of the moderator in question is about the use of bold in a font". Many of the user a warning. Let us know what I mean. Either way I believe the existing answers are misleading than simply "unfortunate". Even more so there is little, if any, need to report it here. The only a single prefix across a snippet of CSS that can be used properly). None of the edits here on meta for addressing certain limitations to comments with regard to deleting/deleted answers. For one, we cannot comment on his answer which shows me it's come up again? And this in its revision history — notice that hidden comments can still be doing if you were paying attention at all. When in doubt, http://caniuse.com is an excellent reference for figuring out which versions of which browsers require prefixes for certain CSS properties. That would be https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current. (Yes, that whatever eventual action a moderator takes, the flags are counted as disputed and it would not make sense of the word, if you're not multiple editors), and expand on them to be harmlessly removed, but it's safe to say you were in such cases, as we can work with locked questions, remove bounties on meta yet to effect some sort of process to be implemented. That being said, you can always post as an answer, but does serve well as commentary, I will post is an answer, please remove that your question didn't actually meet our site. And that's just one reason. There are no systems in place to track bounty patterns that I think it's acceptable. There was no special "offensive" comment flag, unlike with higher privileges (20k+ users can vote to close but you can post comments, you can always post a widely applicable situation that is too generic for benchmarks to even be found here. Note that it's still pending), and it usually doesn't need to tell us exactly what doesn't seem genuinely concerned that people are involved. Anyway, hope it helps! I'd done something like this before... Wait. I have. You're telling me it's safe to say you were in limbo. Yes, that's a duplicate, so than I was, and indeed, you for bringing this up. I think the version is significant enough to lang-css, but that would break questions tagged font-bold are decidedly not about this the other day. I once posted a question of my own content. I shan't get into the question to a certain degree, so we can focus on more pressing issues. But whatever, I deleted it. If you believe your post is to, well, moderate, not summarily click buttons", but neither do we have far more of them than moderators) and as such it didn't need to cast a vote if you can do that also if you don't like the technology it's about Flash. Or any form of 2D animation for that matter. Basically, your comment on his answer which shows up in our flag queue. Or to put it another way: as web development things, despite them not referring specifically to my case, or is this a bug that can do that also if you like!) and then you can grant access to moderator tools privilege. It's simply list the editors you use in your edit history. You need a line break, but it won't have left for the day; your flag handling stats on Stack Overflow. I don't need or wish to be a bug, so there is little, if any, need to report it comes to technology, benchmarks alone are exempt from being closed as duplicates. Also, for crying out loud, Stack Overflow, but on several other sites as well), and official events set out by the default hint, which actually limits users to the ability at all. It's not. It's as the answer belongs to its author, and the edit doesn't appear ill-intentioned in any way, I'd say it's actually finally completed now. Yes, special "offensive" comment flag, unlike with post to, so instead of migrating we have to deal with on a Gravatar account, because it's also a legitimate answer when you've stated plainly yourself that it's not an answer. At the end of the day, it's all about whether a comment with line breaks and paragraphs?) But I just don't see how your answer should be self-contained, even if it really has to come to stick with a prefix, really. This led him on an answer-unaccepting spree, subverting (or, in his own words, what you used was an incorrect way of formatting a list. I answered a question, and the asker wrote thanks for the sake of why something works this way or put on hold, so your feature that was introduced post-CSS2.1. The migration was rejected because the question was flagged.) If it's a duplicate, flag being marked as "helpful"), and then grant access to Gravatar. If you want to use that Gravatar, simply change your email address in your own writing and formatting. Plus, I were just talking about this the moderator in question to avoid handling stats on Stack Overflow. I don't migrate from meta to main either for the same reason. There are extremely inconclusive unless tailored to very, very specific setups. Either you have no incentive to approve it. If you believe your post in its revision history — notice that there's a bigger conflict going on (as is usually the case with users for as long as they are generally OK, it's not appropriate to call attention to my answer, for that. The flags themselves have no reason why the moderator deleted it, and no way to ask why do you say that it's not work, then the solution should be there. Funny, another moderator and I personally think it's better to open a link in a new tab for this week until you edit more posts. You already have more pressing issues. But whatever, I deleted your post, but I would have not. Frankly I was surprised that is used in writing over the duplicate. If you cannot vote to you and just before you tried to dispute it. If the flag a new question for immediate removal, make sure to explain to us with a dud flag that we undelete it first. That's as much more elegantly and succinctly than I transgressed with my question? You have existed in the first place. Why am I still here? Your question gets closed for having too many flags you have left for the question fully, as opposed to an.

---

Generated using [Flack Overstow](https://stackapps.com/questions/306/flack-overstow-generate-spam-from-stack-exchange-posts).

Comment: "You'll be seeing more questions like this in the rest of the page". Hmmmm.

Comment: +1 for the edit.  Greatly improved the post.

Comment: This answer seems to be poorly formatted and a large wall of text.  Please [edit] it to make it more readable by the community.  Thank you.

Comment: Btw, I love the last bit at the bottom - "You have existed in the first place. Why am I still here?"

Comment: You've been waiting for a chance to use that, haven't you? ;)

Comment: This answer will appear as a result for every search query.

Comment: This totally beats Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: needs more nigerian princes.

Comment: dang it you beat me to it ;)

Comment: Post when you save. As others have any deleted answers? Well, how you bans work is that we don't just mark it as not a duplicate. It's a polyglo, and downvote, but after a while, I get fed up and just downvote is best. If there is already two badges similar to what you have access to these tools, you tried if you want answers. Normally, a single line comment (akin C and request a new IP address. If you want to look at someone is directing it at me, I mean for "that site" is this: Stack Exchange. I'll agree, it is confusing, _but it was Microsoft's decision. Maybe it was chosen._

Comment: This results in the future. I also think we should merge sailsjs into sails.js as C++ requires an explicit return type to be int.

Comment: VLQ flag raised as this is in English.

Answer (score 80):

How about a Spam Exchange ?

*Q&A for Spammer Enthusiasts where you can learn spamming tips and tricks*.

Common questions :

- How to spoof an email properly ?
- How to make my SPAM live longer on Stack Exchange
- Jon Spam Facts

> [image]

Comment: Finally, a site where I can discuss potted meat! The guys at [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) just don't understand...

Comment: You should suggest it on Area Fifty Spam

Comment: [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

Comment: @Oded Closed Question closed for non-spam.

This question was recognized as non-spam by the community. Please correct this post to add non-sense publicity in it or else it is likely to get deleted.

Comment: Go ahead and [propose](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology) it. :)

Comment: **Spam Review** - A site for posting spam you are planning to send for peer review

Comment: +1 for Jon Spam Facts

Comment: @voretaq7 [Done](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62657/spam-review)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn How to send 100,000 emails weakly?

Answer (score 14):

There's a new proposal on Area 51 to help alleviate this problem: [Spam Review](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62657/spam-review)

[image: Spam Review]

---

There appear to be some super fun party people who are trying to downvote and close this proposal. There's even been **SIX** people who had the audacity to *downvote* Jon Spam:

[image: Jon Spam was DOWNVOTED]

We *can't* let that happen! We *can't* let them win!

---

## *Spam Review needs YOU*

[image: Spam Review needs YOU]

Join the cause! **FIGHT** for increased spam quality!

---

If you don't, just remember that when Uncle *Spam* pulls the trigger, it will be *your* fault:

[image: It will be YOUR fault]

Comment: I think that last image is...kind of in poor taste.

Comment: @jdarnel27 Why?  That's a perfectly reasonable interpretation of how the United States Congress works.

Comment: @TheGrinch Maybe that's why I thought it was in poor taste =P

Answer (score 9):

Introduce *Spamutation points*™ alongside Reputation points, because spammers have their own reputation to think of, too.  There will be a much better incentive to produce higher-quality spam.

When a post is deleted due to sufficient spam flags, or due to a moderator deleting it for being spam:

- +10 spamutation to the poster for having a post deleted as spam.
- +2 spamutation to the poster for every downvote and every close vote on the post.
- +1 spamutation to the poster for every view (prior to deletion) on the post.
- +1 spamutation to the poster for every click on a link in the spam post.
- +15 spamutation to the poster if the post is linked from a meta post.

This requires a new tab in the User Profile page, "Spamutation", preferably just to the right of "Reputation", modeled after the exiting "Reputation" tab.

Also, this requires a new Stack Exchange URL, `/spamutation`, modeled after the existing `/reputation` URL.

```
total votes: 28
23  12868777 (10)
24  12868777 (2)
24  12868777 (2)
24  12868777 (2)
25  12868777 (1)
25  12868777 (1)
25  12868777 (1)
25  12868777 (1)
25  12868777 (1)
25  12868777 (1)
25  12868777 (1)
25  12868777 (1)
-- 2012-10-13 spam +24   = 25        
23  12903900 (10)
24  12903900 (2)
24  12903900 (2)
24  12903900 (2)
24  12903900 (2)
24  12903900 (2)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
25  12903900 (1)
26  12903900 (15)
-- 2012-10-14 spam +45   = 70        

** spam rep today: 45
** spam rep this week (2013-10-13 - 2013-10-19): 69
** spam rep this month (2013-10-01 - 2013-10-31): 69
** spam rep this quarter (2013-10-01 - 2013-12-31): 69
** spam rep this year (2013-01-01 - 2013-12-31): 69
** spam rep from bonuses: 0
** total spam rep 70 :)

days represented 2
spam rep cap was reached via spam rep from downvotes *only* on 0 days
earned at least 200 spam reputation on 0 days
earned 0 reputation from suggested edits
```

Of course, spammers need to be notified of increases in their spamutation too.  This results in a pinkish brown (spam-colored) "+x" that appears in the top bar where normal reputation increases are usually reported in real time.

[image: Spamutation Notification]

And last, but not least, spadges (spam badges)!

[image: Spadges!]

A spadge is earned by having your first post deleted as spam, having a spam post reach 100 views before being deleted, and getting 10 clicks on links in the spam post before being deleted.

Comment: Escape from [spamsara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%83s%C4%81ra).

Answer (score 5):

Spam wizard should be introduced. "Post spam" button should be added next to "Ask a question" button. After clicking it, there should be a series of questions regarding the desired spam content:

- general spam type (Nigerian scam, Replica watches, Penis enlargement, etc.)
- style (wall of punctuation-less text or large red font with exclamation marks or just a link with a tempting text)
- list of SE sites user wishes to post their spam to (all checked by default)
- how many times should the spam be posted, possibly with configured interval (in nanoseconds) between automatic repostings
- etc.

After successful spam configuration a message would appear: "Congratulations! Your spam was posted and automatically deleted. Thank you for your cooperation!".

Answer (score 4):

All seriousness aside, to improve the quality of our spam, we should fight back with the same tools that they use. What this means is that when a post is marked as spam, the poster's personal email address should be placed instead of his posting with a message that says : *Send all your hate mail right here.*

Unfortunately, I have to post this from my exile in Nigeria, but if you click that **UP button** over there, I'll have enough rep to go back and reclaim my fortune from my father the king.