# The side-by-side diffs should make it clear when a link is added

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, revisions-list

On [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/222381/revisions):

> [image: meta side-by-side]

> [image: meta side-by-side markdown]

On [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21930826/revisions) (rev 2):

> [image: so side-by-side]

> [image: so side-by-side markdown]

As you can see, on SO you can't easily notice that a link was added in the side-by-side view. This way [spam can get through the suggested edits review process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222369/spam-and-inattentive-reviewers).

Comment: Related: [Suggested edits that change links should jump out and punch reviewers in the face](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142919/suggested-edits-that-change-links-should-jump-out-and-punch-reviewers-in-the-fac) (I don't think it's a duplicate, as it deals with *changing* links, not adding them.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was solved by [forcing the Markdown diff view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230281/115866) in the review interface if a link was changed (and adding a link counts as a change there).